# How to place the text in front of my image

Tags: html, css, image, text

I am a beginner in coding and I want to place the text in front of the picture. I am using Komodo.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output. POST CODE not PICTURES of code

Comment: Just click edit, then the `[<>]` snippet editor button and paste your code into the panes. Get an image from placeholder.com

Comment: You also need to always use `https:// ` in links (or http:// if they use that)

Answer (score 0):

you can do like this:

```css
div#container {
  position: relative;
}

div#container img {
  width: 100vw;
}

div#container p {
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 30px;
  color: #fff;
  z-index: 10;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <img src="https://wallpapershome.com/images/wallpapers/love-image-2560x1440-8k-21488.jpg" alt="test_img" />
  
  <p> You can put your text here like this ! </p>

<div>
```